# how to convert a 1d Numpy array into an array of pairs?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a one dimensional numpy array, for example looking like :

`[500.774994, 2837.050049, 492.190002, 2840.379883, 475.800018, 2828.725098]`

Assuming the size of the array is a multiple of 2, how could i convert it into an array of pairs of the following shape ?

`[(500.774994, 2837.050049), (492.190002, 2840.379883), (475.800018, 2828.725098)]`

or

`[[500.774994, 2837.050049], [492.190002, 2840.379883], [475.800018, 2828.725098]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a `reshape`:

```
a = np.array([500.774994, 2837.050049, 492.190002, 2840.379883, 475.800018, 2828.725098])

a.reshape(-1, 2)

array([[ 500.774994, 2837.050049],
       [ 492.190002, 2840.379883],
       [ 475.800018, 2828.725098]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = [500.774994, 2837.050049, 492.190002, 2840.379883, 475.800018, 2828.725098]
list(zip(x[::2],x[1:]))
```

Output:

```
[(500.774994, 2837.050049),
 (492.190002, 492.190002),
 (475.800018, 2840.379883)]
```

Comment: Maybe check if `len(x)` may be divided by two? Just for safety...

Comment: No need since `zip` does not require 2 arrays to have same length

Comment: it works, thanks @ExplodingGayFish ! (what a crazy name ^^).

Comment: @MartinSteinborn dont worry i already handle this case, and to focus only on the transformation matter i specified we were assuming it was dividable by 2 in the  post :) .